# Is it safe to expose your AWS ACCESS_KEY_ID online?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to generate a presigned upload URL to AWS S3, and this is the URL that I receive:

```
iex(3)> ExAws.S3.presigned_url(ExAws.Config.new(:s3), :put, "myapp-staging", "picture.png")
{:ok, "https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myapp-staging/picture.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=MY-KEY-IS-HERE%2F20191215%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20191215T220120Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=df6a289130d12e3e8175457b5f8e21a8840f9b5713134ac83c91368332b84eed"}
```

Notice MY-KEY-IS-HERE - the AWS access key id is part of the url generated.

Is it safe for this API key to be publicly visible to anyone online asking for a presigned upload URL?

Comment: Is it just AWS_ACCESS_KEY? Probably fine. It is basically just a username. The one you need to  keep secret is the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Answer (score 0):

ACCESS_KEY_ID is ok but SECRET ACCESS Key will be cause the security issue.